# Getting error "Cannot convert value of type 'listItem' to expected argument type 'String?'"

Tags: arrays, swift, watchkit

I'm trying to load a list I already have within an iPhone viewcontroller to a watch, I can't figure out how to display just the name to the watchface. I keep getting the error in the title over the "rowModel" in parenthesis at the end of the code.

```
struct listItem: Codable {
        var name: String
        var type: String
        var completed: Int
    }

class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: WKInterfaceTable!
    var tableData: [listItem] = []
    
    
    override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
        // Configure interface objects here.
        loadTableData()
    }
    
    override func willActivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
    }
    
    override func didDeactivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
    }
    private func loadTableData() {
        tableView.setNumberOfRows(tableData.count, withRowType: "RowController")
        
        for (index, rowModel) in tableData.enumerated() {
            if let rowController = tableView.rowController(at: index) as? RowController {
                rowController.rowLabel.setText(rowModel)
                
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty clear. Take a moment for a closer look at the error message: *Cannot convert…* indicates a type mismatch error. The first type `listItem` is the proposed, wrong type and the second type `String?` is the expected, right type.

You want to display *just the name to the watchface* but you pass the entire object containing `name`, `type` and `completed`.

So replace

```
rowController.rowLabel.setText(rowModel)
```

with

```
rowController.rowLabel.setText(rowModel.name)
```